BUG Eclipse Scout Method getConfiguredLabelHorizontalAlignment
I think I found a bug in Eclipse Scout. The problem is that I can position the label differently for a field, for example for a StringField, but settings for the alignment do not work. The method getConfiguredLabelHorizontalAlignment sets a variable in Java, but this variable does not exist in the UI library at all. You can also see this on the Eclipse Scout widgets page.
https://scout.bsi-software.com/widgets/?dl=widget-stringfield
In the following image, for example, "Label Right" should also be to the right of the input field or "Label Center" in the middle.

https://scout.bsi-software.com/jswidgets/#string-field
If I knew where and how to report the bug, I would do so, but the Bugzilla page seems to be outdated for that, at least I would assume so based on the warning on the page.

You are right, this functionality has never been implemented for the current UI and we should have removed the property.
You can report bugs on our GitHub page: https://github.com/eclipse-scout/scout.rt/issues
